# Api в Laravel 5, как определить юзера

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

Всем привет, использую Vue.js на фронте, хочу сделать подгрузку данных через ajax запросы. 
Собственно с самими запросами я разобрался.
Но как определять юзера по запросу api? Например хочу вывести данные пользователя на странице, как только он заходит на сайт через ajax, но как узнать какой именно это юзер?
Есть ли русскоязычные материалы по тому, как это дело настроить с Laravel?

P.s. Laravel Passport не предлагать , мне не нужна OAUTH аутентификация.

Comment: используй JWT, не нужно костыли изобретать

Comment: да, кстати JWT тоже можно забыл про него :) [laravel-jwt](https://github.com/codecasts/laravel-jwt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на там же есть через токен, генерируй токен, и вперед, добавь через миграцию поле api_token

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('api_token')->unique();
});

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('api_token');
});
```

/config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    ....,
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
]
```

При регистрации пользователя создавай сразу строку уникалдьную при помощи str_random и можешь еще от нее взять какой нить хэш, ну и потом соответственно этот api_token привесь как csrf поле в axios

Comment: По-умолчанию? я не нашёл этого в документации. Нашёл только Passport. 
Можете поделиться ссылкой, где описывается, как это осуществить?